# find query in one to many relationship

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many

Support i have a document structure as follows

```
var order = {
order_id : "1234",
plan_name: "Basic plan",
app_id:["app-id-1","app-id-2"]
}
```

It has one to many relationship structure.
i inserted it in mongo like this

```
db.orders.insert(order)
```

I also created index on `order_id` and `app_id`.
Now , i have an `app_id` , i want to find its `order_id`.

How to write query to find
I know i need to use 
`db.orders.find({"app_id":""})` , but app_id is an array. 
Or is there a other technique i am missing ?

Comment: Something like `db.orders.find({ app_id: { $in: ["app-id-1", "app-id-2"] } }` More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You can query on arrays in several ways.
If you want to find all orders with app-id-1 as a value in the app_id array you can simply query

```
app_id: "app-1-id"
```

This will return all orders which have that value in their array.
if you want to find all orders which have a set of app ids you can query

```
app_id: {$all: <array_of_app_ids>}
```

To find all orders which contain only a specific set of ids and no others you can pair $all with $size

```
app_id: {$all: <array_of_app_ids>, $size: <array_of_app_ids.length>}
```

but if you pass a single value, mongoDB will return all entries which have that value in their array